# UpdateModelException ClassCastException in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, el, classcastexception

I have a facelets page with a ui:repeat tag that outputs the rows of an HTML table and each row accepts user input. This works fines. I also have a second set of data that I output using the same page and repeater (just different data). The backing bean supporting this page is ConversationScoped.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cloneBuilderBean.pageTemplate}" var="row" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
    <td>#{row.label}</td>
    <td><h:inputText value=#{row.value}/></td>
  </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

The problem I have is when the user clicks an h:commandButton to "continue" to the next page. This really just redisplays the current page but the collection of the repeater has been updated to a new set of data. From my debugging, it doesn't look like I ever even get to my action method that should fire as a result of clicking the commandButton to go to the next page. The stack trace below also doesn't show any signs of hitting my code. Any thoughts on how to resolve this error?

```
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: java.lang.ClassCastException
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:853)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:735)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:525)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.processUpdates(UIRepeat.java:748)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1231)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.setValue(ArrayELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:197)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:286)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:74)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:818)
    ... 41 more
```

---

**Update**: the relevant bean code is this:

```
private int[] part1,part2;
private int[] currentPart; //pointer to part1 or part2
private List<SelectItem> pageTemplate;

public String openItem(String value){
    conversation.begin();

    //database dummy data...
    pageTemplate = new ArrayList(4);
    pageTemplate.add(new SelectItem("Data1"));
    pageTemplate.add(new SelectItem("Data2"));
    pageTemplate.add(new SelectItem("Data3"));
    pageTemplate.add(new SelectItem("Data4"));

    //database dummy data...
    part1 = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < part1.length; i++){
        part1[i] = i+1;
    }
    currentPart = part1;

    return "page2";
}

public String next(){
    //database dummy data...
    part2 = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < part2.length; i++){
        part2[i] = i+2;
    }
    currentPart = part2;
    return "page2";
}
```

the relevant view code is:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{CloneBuilderBean.pageTemplate}" var="row" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td>#{row.value}</td>
        <td width="300">
            <h:inputHidden id="val" value="#{CloneBuilderBean.currentPart[status.index]}" />
            <p:slider for="val" step="1" style="width:90%;" minValue="0" maxValue="7" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>

<h:commandButton value="display part 2" action="#{CloneBuilderBean.next()}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
>     at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.setValue(ArrayELResolver.java:257)

I reproduced your problem. It turns out that `#{CloneBuilderBean.currentPart[status.index]}` is been set with a `Integer` instead of an `int`. It works for me when I replace `int[]` by `Integer[]`.

When I tried to reproduce your problem on Tomcat 7.0.19 instead of Glassfish 3.1.1, I got a more clear exception from its EL parser:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Unable to add an object of type [java.lang.Integer] to an array of objects of type [int]
>     at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.setValue(ArrayELResolver.java:96)

Comment: Hmm, that would in turn suggest that the model has changed somewhere between restore view phase and update model values phase. Is your managed bean logic really written as such? Perhaps you're somewhere abusing a `valueChangeListener` to do that job? In any way, you should change the managed bean logic as such so that the model change takes place during invoke action phase only.

Comment: Interesting. Could you try to create the smallest possible view (just content of `<h:body>` is sufficient) and managed bean (just the properties/actions (no getter/setters) is sufficient) and provide it in your question so that we can copy'n'paste'n'run it to see it ourselves?

Comment: Ok. I created a sample project. The code is a little different but it's doing semantically the same thing as my original code and gives the same error. You can get the code here: http://www.mediafire.com/?a9na4cfa371a7ms

Comment: It looks like it might have something to do with <h:inputHidden id="val" value="#{CloneBuilderBean.currentPart[status.index]}" />. Am I not able to dynamically specify the element of an array in the repeater? It works ok during output but maybe during the postback it explodes?